# Google Analytics Opt-Out for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am having trouble implementing the opt-out preference for Google Analytics on Android.  I am using Analytics v4.  I have the preference screen working but it does not seem to prevent information being sent to Google Analytics when I uncheck the box.  Do I need to check the opt-out preference in each activity or am I missing something in my PreferenceActivity?

Here is my code so far.

```
package edu.ncsu.oncampus;


import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
     if (key.equals("trackingPreference")) {
       GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setAppOptOut(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, true));
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem.  I ended up using a two step process for the solution.  The first step was to register the preference change in the Settings page I created. (Note that I used a checkbox setting for this, so I had to use the opposite value of the checkbox to set the opt-out value.)  I have posted only the relevant code here.

```
Settings.java

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();

    SharedPreferences userPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    userPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener () {

          @Override
          public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) 
          {
            if (key.equals("trackingPreference")) {
                GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setAppOptOut(!sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false));
            } 
          }
        }); 
}
```

I also check the setting in the main activity when I launch the app and set the opt out setting.

```
HomeActivity.java

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    SharedPreferences userPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean isOptedOut = userPrefs.getBoolean("trackingPreference", false);
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAppOptOut(!isOptedOut);
}
```